# Lua - Getting a Localized Variable or Function without using the Debug Library with 2 seperate scripts

Tags: lua

Ok so I am using a object orientated environment, I can make several scripts that may or may not connect with each other, all depending on if I want them to connect or not, and I want to get a function that is localized `local myfunc = function() end` from a different object that can handle code, from this point forward I will be calling these objects "Scripts" as they are what they are called in the game and are easily used for me to tell people what I am talking about even if they are not formally used as a name to suggest such a thing.

So lets say I have Script 1 with this code:

```
local myfunc = function() return true end
```

and I have Script 2 with a blank sheet, I want to make it so I can get myfunc without touching the debug library, making the original script a module script and returning the function, and this has to stay in 2 separate scripts. That is all for the requirements if you are wondering. I expect this can be done and I hope someone out there has the knowledge on how to do something like this clean and efficiently!

Comment: At the moment of Script2 starting the `myfunc` function created by Script1 is probably doesn't exist anymore.  Local objects are garbage-collected when not needed.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of a local variable is that it's *local*; other people can't touch it. The traditional means of having one script access data from another are modules or global variables. Both options which you have declared that you can't/won't do.

Your requirements reduce the set of possible solutions to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Lua chunks can have `return` statements. To return a single function:

```
return function()
  return true
end
```

To return a table with multiple functions:

```
return {
  myFunc = function()
    return true
  end,
  myOtherFunc = function()
    return false
  end,
}
```

Comment: Isn't that just modules? ;)

Comment: @NicolBolas: Yes, it is. That seems to be what the OP needs, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @luther - OP is unable to modify Script1.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: I don't see where he says that in the question. He doesn't say any thing about how he wants to connect the scripts, so I assume that part is open.

Comment: I put in the text that I would like to not use modules.

Comment: You don't have to use modules to edit a chunk to have a return statement and/or to not ignore the return list of a chunk.

Comment: @James: Maybe you should edit your question? This sentence is explicitly asking for modules: "I want to make it so I can get myfunc without touching the debug library, making the original script a module script and returning the function, and this has to stay in 2 separate scripts."